# How to web scrape without the text turning into an giant array?

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping

I am supposed to create script in Python for saving the views from varioues wiki pages formattes almost like Python dictionary

I use this code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

expURL = 'https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/en.wikipedia/all-access/all-agents/Albert_Einstein/daily/2015100100/2015100100'

uClient = uReq(expURL)
page = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
```

But it turns the text into a big array and I cannot work with it like a dictionary anymore. When I copy-paste the data into my code, it works as I would like it to work. Is there any possible function or way to keep the data as it is without turning it into an array?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: pass it in beautiful soup as html.parser u will get all content as html.

Comment: I tried this: page_raw = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser'), the printed then page_raw, but the results doesn't show the HTML markup language at all, just the text... I am quite new to this and really don't know what I'm doing wrong